# Access Enum in javascript from JSON object

Tags: javascript, json, rest, enums

I have a JSON object that came from my REST service.  On the server and on the front end I've declared constants that have the same name but complement each other.

They share some data, but mostly each constant has only things relevant to either the front end or back end.  On the front end, what is the preferred way to map the front end constant from the back end constant?

On the backend, `BuildingType` is an enum.  In the JSON object below, its the first field `buildingType`

```
{buildingType: "CANNON", hp: 100, level: 1, location: Object, name: "Cannon"}
```

Here is the javascript code to map it to the front end version of the constant

```
    var imageMetadata = eval("clashalytics.Images." + building.buildingType);
    // In this case, the eval is the same as 
    var imageMetadata = clashalytics.Images.CANNON;
```

I'm a java developer primarily, fyi.

Comment: Not exactly sure what you are asking, could improve it to make clearer. But that eval code is equivalent to `clashalytics.Images[building.buildingtype]` w/o the eval needed. Eval is generally not a very good idea unless absolutely necessary as it's overhead can be high.

Comment: I knew eval wasn't the way to go, just a quick  way to get it working.  Tried that out and it works! thanks.  Feel free to post as an answer.  Although I'm going to wait to mark as answer to see if there are other options.

Answer (score 1):

Use [array-like notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Object_literals).

```
eval("clashalytics.Images." + building.buildingType)
```

is equivalent to

```
clashalytics.Images[building.buildingType]
```

You could define a getter like so

```
function getConst(target, path) {
  return target[path];
}
```

and use it

```
getConst(clashalytics.Images, building.buildingtype)
```

> **Don't use eval needlessly!**
>
> eval() is a dangerous function, which executes the code it's passed
>   with the privileges of the caller. If you run eval() with a string
>   that could be affected by a malicious party, you may end up running
>   malicious code on the user's machine with the permissions of your
>   webpage / extension. More importantly, third party code can see the
>   scope in which eval() was invoked, which can lead to possible attacks
>   in ways to which the similar Function is not susceptible.
>
> eval() is also generally slower than the alternatives, since it has to
>   invoke the JS interpreter, while many other constructs are optimized
>   by modern JS engines.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you should never use: `Eval()`. It has `security implications` and can interfere with the scope chain. (`Eval()` can access and modify a variable in its outer scope, whereas `Function cannot`).

Secondly, "Javascript is a weakly typed language, which means you don’t declare variables to have a specific type beforehand". Please take a look at this website [enums-in-javascript](https://stijndewitt.wordpress.com/2014/01/26/enums-in-javascript/) from `Stijn de Witt`

As a workaround you could use the `Object.freeze()`, well explained on `https://developer.mozilla.org`: [Object.freeze()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/freeze)

So, your code will look like:

`var Cannon = Object.freeze({"hp":100, "level":1, "location":Object, "name": "Cannon"})`

And then you can access your `Cannon enumerators` like a normal object: `Cannon.hp` will give you 100, etc...

Please, let me know if you have any question.